# android notifydatasetchanged does not finish in time

Tags: android, notifydatasetchanged

I have an ArrayAdapter which I notify of some changes (notifydatasetchanged).
Directly after, I want to work on the changed dataset, however the methods working on the changed set apparently start before the dataset has been changed.

I have tried a while loop:

```
    while (l.getChildCount()<2){

                }
```

Where l is my dataset and the number of children in the beginning was on, later two.
However, this solution loops endlessly.
 My dataset IS changed, I have tested that - only not before I can work on it in the same method where I do the changing.
How can I fix that?

Comment: well post the portion that has the problem so ppl can help you, posting this, wont get you answers..

Comment: posting code sometimes will not either. Anyway I have programmed around it, meaning I do not need to change the dataset at a point where it is not changed anymore. So what do I do with this question?

Comment: okay sir,good to hear, yes you can delete it then, since nobody answered..